# Magento API duplicate SKU's

Tags: magento, duplicates

Using the Magento API to import ~60.000 products I manage to import duplicate SKU's in Magento, normally this throws an 'Duplicate SKU' exception but somehow it just add's double products.

Anyone knows what's going wrong (some index caching or something?)?

This is the (relevant) part of the code of the import script:

```
<?php 
/** 
 * @param      $data 
 * @param bool $retry 
 * @return bool 
 */ 
public function updateProduct($data, $retry = true) { 
    //Calculate product hash 
    $hash  = md5(serialize($data)); 

    try { 
        $manageStock = 0; 
        if($data->qty <= 0) { 
            $manageStock = 1; 
        } 
        $result = $this->client->catalogProductUpdate($this->session, $data->prefixed_sku, array( 
            'categories' => $data->categories, 
            'status' => empty($data->status) ? '1' : (int) $data->status, 
            'cost'  => $data->cost, 
            'price' => $data->price, 
            'tax_class_id' => '2', 
            'visibility' => '4', 
            'stock_data' => array( 
                'qty' => $data->qty, 
                'is_in_stock' => $data->is_in_stock, 
                'manage_stock' => $manageStock 
            ), 
            'additional_attributes' => array('cost' => $data->cost) 
        ), null, 'sku'); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) { 
        $result = $this->exceptionLogAndRetry($e, 'updateProduct', $retry, $data); 
    } 
    return $result; 
} 

/** 
 * @param      $data 
 * @param bool $retry 
 * @return bool 
 */ 
public function addProduct($data, $retry = true) { 
    //Calculate product hash 
    $hash = md5(serialize($data)); 

    if(!$this->attributeSet) { 
        $attributeSets = $this->client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($this->session); 
        foreach($attributeSets as $attributeSet) { 
            if(strtolower($attributeSet->name) == 'default') { 
                $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet; 
            } 
        } 
        if(!$this->attributeSet) { 
            $this->attributeSet = current($attributeSets); 
        } 
    } 
    try { 
        $stock = array( 
            'qty' => $data->qty, 
            'is_in_stock' => $data->is_in_stock, 
            'use_config_manage_stock' => $data->use_config_manage_stock 
        ); 

        if($data->qty <= 0) { 
            $stock['manage_stock'] = 1; 
        } 

        $result = $this->client->catalogProductCreate($this->session, 'simple', $this->attributeSet->set_id, $data->prefixed_sku, array( 
            'categories' => $data->categories, 
            'websites' => array($data->website_id), 
            'name' => $data->name, 
            'description' => $data->description, 
            'short_description' => $data->short_description, 
            'weight' => $data->weight, 
            'cost'  => $data->cost, 
            'status' => empty($data->status) ? '1' : (int) $data->status, 
            'url_key' => $data->url_key, 
            'url_path' => $data->url_path, 
            'visibility' => '4', 
            'price' => $data->price, 
            'tax_class_id' => '2', 
            'meta_title' => $data->meta_title, 
            'meta_keyword' => $data->meta_keyword, 
            'meta_description' => $data->meta_description, 
            'stock_data' => $stock, 
            'additional_attributes' => array('cost' => $data->cost) 
        )); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) { 
        $result = $this->exceptionLogAndRetry($e, 'addProduct', $retry, $data); 

     } 

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
    { 
        $cur = $i; 
        if ($cur == 1) 
        { 
            $cur = ''; 
        } 

        if (!empty($data->{"product_image$cur"}) && file_exists($data->{"product_image$cur"}) && is_numeric($result)) 
        { 
            $file = array( 
                'content' => base64_encode(@file_get_contents($data->{"product_image$cur"})), 
                'mime'    => $data->{'product_mime'.$cur} 
            ); 
            try { 
                $imgRes = $this->client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate( 
                    $this->session, 
                    $result, 
                    array('file' => $file, 'label' => '', 'position' => '100', 'types' => array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image'), 'exclude' => 0) 
                ); 
            } 
            catch (Exception $e) { 
                //Do nothing 
            } 
        } 

    } 

    $return = $result; 

    return $return; 
}
```

Comment: I found the same thing... Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I just increased the time between requests to bypass the issue